# Deserializing JSON in WP7

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I have this JSON which I am trying to read on Windows Phone. I've been playing with `DataContractJsonSerializer` and Json.NET but had not much luck, especially reading each 'entry':

```
{"lastUpdated":"16:12","filterOut":[],"people":
[{"ID":"x","Name":"x","Age":"x"},{"ID":"x","Name":"x","Age":"x"},{"ID":"x","Name":"x","Age":"x"}],
 "serviceDisruptions":
  {
    "infoMessages":
    ["blah blah text"],
    "importantMessages":
    [],
    "criticalMessages":
    []
  }
}
```

All I care about is the entries in the people section. Basically I need to read and iterate through the entries (containing the ID, Name, Age values) and add them to a Collection or class. (I am populating a listbox afterwards.)

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: You example is not valid json, please post the real thing :-)

Comment: Ok, I have just changed the text and formated it into seperate lines. Why do you say it is not valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to deserialize your JSON string using the following code.  This was tested in a .NET 4 console application, and hopefully will work in WP 7 as well.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PersonCollection));

string json =  "{\"lastUpdated\":\"16:12\",\"filterOut\":[],\"people\": [{\"ID\":\"a\",\"Name\":\"b\",\"Age\":\"c\"},{\"ID\":\"d\",\"Name\":\"e\",\"Age\":\"f\"},{\"ID\":\"x\",\"Name\":\"y\",\"Age\":\"z\"}], \"serviceDisruptions\": { \"infoMessages\": [\"blah blah text\"], \"importantMessages\": [], \"criticalMessages\": [] } }";

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
{
    var people = (PersonCollection)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

    foreach(var person in people.People)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Name: {1}, Age: {2}", person.ID, person.Name, person.Age);
    }
}
```

Using the following data classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonCollection
{
    [DataMember(Name = "people")]
    public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks you, ive modified it nicely to populate my collection. The tricky bit for me was how to enumerate it but the PersonCollection seems to sort that out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses Json.NET. It deserializes the JSON string first to XML, then uses LINQ to XML to iterate all people nodes and convert them to instances of the `Person` class.

```
private class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

// deserializes your JSON and creates a list of Person objects from it
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // your JSON
    string json =
        "{\"lastUpdated\":\"16:12\",\"filterOut\":[],\"people\": " +
        "[{\"ID\":\"x\",\"Name\":\"x\",\"Age\":\"x\"},{\"ID\":\"x\",\"Name\":\"x\",\"Age\":\"x\"},{\"ID\":\"x\",\"Name\":\"x\",\"Age\":\"x\"}]," +
        "\"serviceDisruptions\":" +
        "{" +
        "\"infoMessages\":" +
        "[\"blah blah text\"]," +
        "\"importantMessages\":" +
        "[]," +
        "\"criticalMessages\":" +
        "[]" +
        "}" +
        "}";

    // deserialize from JSON to XML
    XDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "root");

    // iterate all people nodes and create Person objects
    IEnumerable<Person> people = from person in doc.Element("root").Elements("people")
                                 select new Person()
                                 {
                                     ID = person.Element("ID").Value,
                                     Name = person.Element("Name").Value,
                                     Age = person.Element("Age").Value
                                 };

    // this is just demonstrating that it worked
    foreach (Person person in people)
        Debug.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

Don't forget the imports:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

And this is how the deserialized JSON looks like as XML document (for the curious people out there):

```xml
<root>
  <lastUpdated>16:12</lastUpdated>
  <people>
    <ID>x</ID>
    <Name>x</Name>
    <Age>x</Age>
  </people>
  <people>
    <ID>x</ID>
    <Name>x</Name>
    <Age>x</Age>
  </people>
  <people>
    <ID>x</ID>
    <Name>x</Name>
    <Age>x</Age>
  </people>
  <serviceDisruptions>
    <infoMessages>blah blah text</infoMessages>
  </serviceDisruptions>
</root>
```