# Cannot parse a downloaded xml file to XDocument in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

I am creating a windows phone 8 app. In it I am downloading a **XML** file from a **URL** using `WebClient`. The downloaded result shows something like this:

```cs
[{"PersonNo":"1","PersonName":"Kaustav","Address":"Kolkata"},{"PersonNo":"2","PersonName":"Jay","Address":"Mumbai"}
{"PersonNo":"3","PersonName":"Rants","Address":"Chennai"}]
```

When I pass this to the `Parse` method of `XDocument` it generates an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

My code is:

```cs
private void getPersons()
{

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpCompleted;
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/test.xml")); 
}
private void HttpCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var loadedData = XDocument.Parse(e.Result); //problem in this line

    //display person info
}
```

Here the URL is changed for security reasons.

So **how to parse this downloaded XML file to XDocument?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloaded string is **not XML** but It is **JSON.** So either use a **JSON parser** (I recommend **Json.net**, it works with Windows Phone) or find a way to tell the server to return XML

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `JsonSerializer`? You can simply use the [Json.NET 6.0.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to achieve this.

[Deserializing JSON in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201971/)

[How to deserialize json data in windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783272/)